# Asignar un Select a un Table en Funcion SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

En una función en SQL Server hay alguna manera de crear una tabla y asignarle el valor de una consulta, algo como

```
CREATE TABLE AuxAlumnos
(
   Id       int,
   Nombre   varchar (10),
   Apellido varchar(10)
);
```

Y a esa tabla asignarle el valor de un `SELECT * FROM Alumnos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se puede o puedes hacer con tablas temporales o tablas concretas te quedara algo similar a esto :

Tabla concreta :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MI_PROCEDIMIENTO
AS

    CREATE TABLE #AuxAlumnos
    (
       Id       int,
       Nombre   varchar (10),
       Apellido varchar(10)
    );

    INSERT  INTO #AuxAlumnos (ID,NOMBRE,APELLIDO) 
    SELECT  ID,NOMBRE,APELLIDO
    FROM    Alumnos
```

Tabla Temporal :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MI_PROCEDIMIENTO
AS

    DECLARE @AuxAlumnos TABLE
    (
          Id       int,
          Nombre   varchar (10),
          Apellido varchar(10)
    )

    INSERT  INTO @AuxAlumnos (ID,NOMBRE,APELLIDO)
    SELECT  ID,NOMBRE,APELLIDO
    FROM    Alumnos
```

luego solo debes hacer el select a la tabla que acabas de crear.

Espero sea de tu ayuda

Saludos

Comment: Que diferencia hay que use @ o #?

Comment: el @ lo utilizas para crear una tabla que solo este dispobible para quien ejecuto el procedimiento y el # se utiliza para crear una tabla visible para todos , eso es a grandes razgos.

Answer (score 2):

Podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3 INTO NUEVATABLA FROM VIEJATABLA
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? no es clara la pregunta.

Tal vez quieras hacer algo como:

> SELECT *FROM  fuMiFuncion('x')

Si fuese así, si se puede hacer.

Comment: Smc, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).